# Schengen Visa via France, but visiting Amsterdam and Reykjavik (Iceland)

Tags: schengen, india, france

I am an Indian National and have a schengen visa via France embassy. I will be visiting Paris for a few days and then return to India.
After a few days, I have to visit Amsterdam and Reykjavik (Iceland) from India.
Would my schengen visa issues from France embassy be valid for the second travel, considering I am not going to France in my second visit.
Please help, slightly urgent.

Comment: Is your visa for one, two, or multiple entries?

Comment: How can you close this as a dupe if you don't even know whether it's multiple entry? Vote to close as unclear, not dupe.